# Way to Automate button clicks of an Android Application

Tags: android, testing, automation, click

Is  there a way to automate the clicking (opening,clicking certain button of the application and finally closing it) with some script or an android application.

Answer (score 9):

Depends on what you're trying to do. For UI testing of your app you can use the build-in support, have a look at http://developer.android.com/training/activity-testing/activity-ui-testing.html or perhaps look into the [UI automation tool](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/uiautomator/index.html).

If what you want to do is emulate user events on any given app, you could use adb to send key or touch events, but it would be a on a very low level

For example:

```
adb shell input keyevent 3
```

Would emulate pressing the home key.

You could also do

```
adb shell input tap 50 50
```

to emulate a touch event at the given coordinate.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [uiautomator](http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing_ui.html) (requires API 16+).

[Robotium](https://code.google.com/p/robotium/) (which also uses the [Android testing framework](http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing_android.html))  is another great testing framework for UI. Same goes for [Espresso](https://code.google.com/p/android-test-kit/wiki/Espresso). You can then write JUnit 3 tests for your app.